# Tor will not install

Tags: tor-install

I had tor working and did not realize firefox is needed to run tor so i uninstalled it.  I tried reinstalling tor after i reinstalled firefox and the installer will launch but freezes up when attempting to connect to the tor network. here is the info copied from the clipboard.  please help.

1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.300 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "G:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
1/13/2017 17:07:19 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
1/13/2017 17:07:22 PM.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
1/13/2017 17:07:22 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
1/13/2017 17:07:26 PM.800 [WARN] Our clock is 52 minutes, 37 seconds behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2017-01-13 23:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
1/13/2017 17:07:26 PM.800 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
1/13/2017 17:07:26 PM.800 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
1/13/2017 17:17:09 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/13/2017 17:17:09 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/13/2017 17:17:09 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/13/2017 17:17:10 PM.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Comment: `[WARN] Our clock is 52 minutes, 37 seconds behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2017-01-13 23:00:00 UTC). Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!`

Comment: You should also consider installing [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) instead of Tor+Firefox separately.